# how to stack elements using CSS

Tags: css

I have four `div` elements in a container:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom-left"></div>
    <div id="bottom-center"></div>
    <div id="fill"></div>
</div>
```

I need to position them as follows:

The top edge of the `top` element should be at the top edge of the container.
The `bottom-left` element should be in the bottom-left corner of the container.
The `bottom-center` element should be centered at the bottom of the container.
The `fill` element will have a fixed width and should take the remaining space vertically.

The problem is that the `fill` element will contain arbitrary text and can be of arbitrary height. I need to put it under the `top` element and place the `bottom-center` under it. the bottom edge of `bottom-left` must align with the bottom of `bottom-center`.

I tried absolute positioning, but it does not work for arbitrary text length.

I would appreciate any help.

EDIT: here is jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/gCg29/
it creates the layout that I want to achieve but with a table.

how to get rid of the table and have the same functionality? notice that if the width of the browser window is insufficient then the elements do not overlap. also notice that if the text grows in length then the left-bottom and under-text elements stick to the text's bottom.

```
                           +-----------------------+
                           |  top (fixed size)     |
                           +-----------------------+
                    +-----------------------------------+
                    |                                   |
                    |                   fill            |
                    |        (arbitrary height,         |
+-----------------+ |         fixed width)              |
|                 | |                                   |
|  bottom-left    | |                                   |
|  (fixed size)   | |                                   |
|                 | |                                   |
|                 | |                                   |
|                 | |                                   |
|                 | |                                   |
|                 | +-----------------------------------+
|                 |      +--------------------------+
|                 |      |bottom-center (fixed size)|
+-----------------+      +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us a quick wireframe of the layout you are shooting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fill {
    margin: 0 auto 50px; /* 50px = height of bottom-center */
    width: 300px;
}

#top, #bottom-center {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#bottom-center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; /* - width / 2 */
}

#bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nXqQr/1/

The important part is `overflow: hidden;` on the container which will make the margin on `#fill` extend its size, so that `#bottom-center` fits in.

Comment: thanks for your help. the problem with this is that if the main window gets too narrow the elements overlap. i need to avoid this. I have edited my original post and included a link to jsfiddle with a layout based on a table that I want to achieve.

Comment: If you really need a table-like layout why don't you use `display: table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot of css, but I think this is what you want. Quite a few things going on here:

1. set #container to `position: relative` so that you can absolutely position the #bottom-left and #bottom-center
2. give #top and #fill `margin: 0 auto` so that they center on the page
3. #bottom-center also gets `left: 50%` to bring to center. Then `margin-left: -width` to bring it fully center
4. #container gets `padding-bottom: 75px` so that #fill doesn't overlap the bottom div

http://jsfiddle.net/34Jpx/2/

```
div { 
    border: 1px dotted lightgray; 
}
div#container { 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%;  
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75px; 
}
div#top { 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 400px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: lightgreen;  
}
div#fill { 
    height: 200px; 
    width: 500px; 
    margin: 0 auto;  
    background: lightblue; 
    border: 2px solid red; 
}
div#bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 99;
}
div#bottom-center {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightyellow;
    z-index: 100;
}​
```

Comment: thank you. this helps but the problem is that if the browser page gets narrower then the elements overlap. I have edited my post and included a link to jsfiddle with what I want to achieve. there the code uses a table and I am looking to redo it without the table.

Answer (score 1):

I have a horrible idea for you. Essentially you're asking for the page gravity to be inverted. Thus:

```
jQuery('body').css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
jQuery(everythingelse).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
```

That will flip the page and then reflip all the elements in place so that they display right-side-up but in the same position after the invert.

Of course, you'll want to support more than just css3 browsers, and I'm sure this is horribly expensive, but I figured it would be a fun, if not entirely useful, answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an invisible div (let's call it inv-div-1) which contains only bottom-left and another one (inv-div-2) which contains all the rest, give them both a float:left; positioning. in the html file inv-div-1 must be positioned before inv-div-2.

Comment: In this way the arbitrary extension of the fill won't influence the other elements.